# How I make that google maps not change the custom icons size of marker?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need create a marker that represents the localization of each user on google maps, I use the google maps api v3, I put the marker on the map, that is easy, but how I make that when the user make zoom the icon doesnt resize , How I do for not resize the icon when zoom change or wherever change??

The reazon for this is that I have a circle image that represents 50 meters of radio of each user, and if the image changed, the radio of circle change.

This is my code:

```
//Creamos el marcador para saber donde esta el usuario
marker:function(map,latLng) {
    //create a marker image with the path to your graphic and the size of your graphic
    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        '/img/marker.png',
        new google.maps.Size(130,130), //size
        null, //origin
        null, //anchor
        new google.maps.Size(130,130) //scale
    );

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: markerImage //set the markers icon to the MarkerImage
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    //when the map zoom changes, resize the icon based on the zoom level so the marker covers the same geographic area
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

        var pixelSizeAtZoom0 = 130; //the size of the icon at zoom level 0
        var maxPixelSize = 130; //restricts the maximum size of the icon, otherwise the browser will choke at higher zoom levels trying to scale an image to millions of pixels

        var zoom = map.getZoom();
        var relativePixelSize = Math.round(pixelSizeAtZoom0*Math.pow(2,zoom)); // use 2 to the power of current zoom to calculate relative pixel size.  Base of exponent is 2 because relative size should double every time you zoom in

        if(relativePixelSize > maxPixelSize) //restrict the maximum size of the icon
            relativePixelSize = maxPixelSize;

        //change the size of the icon
        marker.setIcon(
            new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                marker.getIcon().url, //marker's same icon graphic
                null,//size
                null,//origin
                null, //anchor
                new google.maps.Size(relativePixelSize, relativePixelSize) //changes the scale
            )
        );
    });


    return marker;
},
```

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? I need to do the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I solved it, but not with the native function of google maps, I make my own code fixing the size image depending of the zoom of map. You can get the zoom... map.getZoom(); and change the image depending on that number.. :)

Comment: Yes, I did the same.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an appropriate use of a marker. Instead, you would use the [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) overlay. The radius of the circle is set in meters.

Comment: I think you don't understundme.. My english is not very good.. :(.. miss the circle... I need to know how make the image size static regards to the zoom change event.

Comment: Markers don't work that way. You would have to manually change the marker image on a `zoom_changed` event and have a different marker image for each zoom level.

Answer (score 0):

For solve the problem I need to scale the image depending of the zoom of map, this is a single solucion but you can improve of here:

```
 var icon = {
        url: 'icon.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(10, 10),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(5, 5)
    };

   var iconMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: icon
    });

var size = RADIUS_SIZE / metersPerPixel(_gmap.getZoom() + 1);
icon.size = new google.maps.Size(size, size);
icon.scaledSize = new google.maps.Size(size, size);
icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(size / 2, size / 2);

iconMarker.setMap(null);

iconMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: iconMarker.getPosition(),
    map: map,
    icon: icon
});
```